# How to use a generator function as a callback inside a promise returned by fetch call?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, redux-saga

```js
return fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    ...options
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function*(response) {
    console.log("httpStatusCode", response.httpStatusCode)
  })
```

Is the above possible ?
I'm not getting the consoled output when the callback function is a generator, which means that the control is not passing to the callback function(generator).
The real reason I want to do it this way is that I have to call another fetch request using the 'call' helper function of redux-saga from the above callback which can be called only from a generator function.

Comment: A generator in a `.then` would seem very strange to me, you only call the `.then` function one time after the promise resolved.

Comment: A generator object in a `then` handler, would simply return the generator object. What you should do is, return a Promise object enclosing the `fetch` call.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do. When the generator function is run it will generate a generator object and it will be passed to the next then stage at where you can initiate the generator. Let's see...

```js
var pr = Promise.resolve(42);
pr.then(function*(n){ yield n; yield n / 2; yield 37})
  .then(it => {console.log(it.next().value);
               console.log(it.next().value);
               console.log(it.next().value);
              });
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is the above possible?

No. The `then` method will simply call the generator function and create a generator, but then <s>discard it</s> fulfill the chained promise, without advancing it. Whenever you want to use generators, you actually need something that runs them.

> The real reason I want to do it this way is that I have to call another fetch request using the 'call' helper function of redux-saga from the above callback which can be called only from a generator function.

Nope. You don't have to call `call` from an arbitrary generator function. You can can call and `yield` a `call()` from a generator function that is *used by redux-saga*.

In any case, your code should look like this:

```
let response = yield take(fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    ...options
}));
response = yield take(response.json());
console.log("httpStatusCode", response.httpStatusCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a long shot here. In order to iterate through a generator function you need to be able to call 'gen.next()'. Which is not possible after providing an anonymous function to '.then'.

I am not familiar with redux-saga, but from what I understand you try something similar.

```
function response (data) {
   console.log("httpStatusCode", data.httpStatusCode);
}


fetch(url, {...})
   .then(function (d) {
      var gen = response(d);
   })
```

You can then pass `gen` to be used in redux-saga.

Comment: Don't declare variables outside of promise callbacks.