# How to call a redux-saga effect from a callback function inside a generator function?

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

My case is as follows:

```
function * uploadFile({file}) {
    Papa.parse(file, {
        header: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(results.data);
            //if errors => call uploadFailed action with yield
            //else yield put(uploadSucceed)
        }
    });
}
```

The commented code cannot be called because it's not a generator function. If I add the `*` to the callback definition, there's no error but it doesn't work.

I've also tried wrapping it in another function that accepts a callback without any luck. Walked through several answers like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760406/how-to-use-a-generator-function-as-a-callback-inside-a-promise-returned-by-fetch) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008229/javascript-call-function-inside-object-from-a-callback-function) but these aren't my case. Also there's no documentation on Papa with redux as far as I've come to see. Any help would be appreciated.

BTW:

```
complete: yield call(someAction) //doesn't work as well.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promisify parsing function and use `call` effect

```
function parse(file) {
  return new Promise((complete, error) => {
    Papa.parse(file, {complete, error})
  })
}

function * uploadFile({file}) {
    try {
      const result = yield call(parse, file);

      // yield put success action

    } catch(error) {

      // yield put error action
    }

}
```